# Is it possible to simplify $(x \pmod a) - (x \pmod b)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have an equation that looks like:

$$\frac{(x \pmod a) - (x \pmod b)}{b}$$

is there any way to simplify this further?

Comment: Probably not. What were you thinking?

Comment: In what set are the operations subtraction and division carried out?

Answer (score 0):

Well, using $a \pmod{b}=a-b\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor$, we can simplify it to
$$\frac{1}{b}\left(b\left\lfloor\frac{x}{b}\right\rfloor-a\left\lfloor\frac{x}{a}\right\rfloor\right)$$
See if you can simplify it further by investigating the floor function.